# How to save each page's data to csv

Tags: html, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a scraping project where I am trying to scrape information off of 13 pages. The page's structure are identical, the only thing that changes are the urls.

I am able to scrape each page using a for loop, and can see each page's information in the terminal. But when I save it to a csv, all that gets saved is the information from the last page, page 13.

I am sure I am missing something, but can't seem to figure out what. Thanks!

I am using python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup to scrape.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

pages = [str(i) for i in range (1,14)]

for page in pages:

    my_url ='Myurl/=' + page

    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"hello"})
    container = containers[0]

    filename = "Full.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    headers= "Aa, Ab, Ac, Ad, Ba, Bb, Bc, Bd\n"
    f.write(headers)

    for container in containers:

        td_tags = container.find_all('td')
        A = td_tags[0]
        B=td_tags[2]

        Aa = A.a.text   
        Ab = A.span.text
        Ac = A.find('span', attrs = {'class' :'boxes'}).text.strip()
        Ad = td_tags[1].text

        Ba = B.a.text   
        Bb = B.span.text
        Bc = B.find('span', attrs = {'class' :'boxes'}).text.strip()
        Bd = td_tags[3].text

        print("Aa:" + Aa)
        print("Ab:" + Ab)
        print("Ac:" + Ac)
        print("Ad:" + Ad)
        print("Ba:" + Ba)
        print("Bb:" + Bb)
        print("Bc:" + Bc)
        print("Bd:" + bd)


        f.write(Aa + "," + Ab + "," + Ac.replace(",", "|") + "," + Ad + "," + Ba + "," + Bb + "," + Bc.replace(",", "|") + "," + Bd + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Edit* Also if anyone has a good idea for how to acknowledge and record what page number each container is from, that would also be helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to append to the file, instead of overwriting it:

```
with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(Aa + "," + Ab + "," + Ac.replace(",", "|") + "," + Ad + "," + Ba + "," + Bb + "," + Bc.replace(",", "|") + "," + Bd + "\n")
```

Comment: Aweseome. Got it to work! Needed to change the "w" to "a" when i created the file as well.

Comment: Any idea how I could signify what page the information is from?

Comment: What is in the page variable?